# Solution of this nonlinear first order differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

It has been many years since I have taken diff. eq., a friend of mine is in the course and asked for my help on this problem and unfortunately it has stumped me

$(x^2 + y^4)dx = -4xy^3dy$

Any help would be great, like I said it has been a long time since I took this course but I don't seem to recall spending much time on non linear equations, so is there a standard approach for solving these types of problems?

Comment: This is an [exact differential equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_differential_equation).

Comment: Ah yes, it makes sense now thank you, had totally forgotten about this haha

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Building off the comment, this is an exact equation.

Let $M=x^2+y^4$ and let $N=4xy^3$.  Then $\frac{dM}{dy}=4y^3$ and $\frac{dN}{dx}=4y^3.$

Let $\Psi(x,y)=\int M\,dx=\frac{x^3}{3}+y^4x+h(y).$

Now we need to figure out what $h(y)$ is.

$\Psi_y(x,y)=4y^3x+h'(y)$

Now set this equal to $N$:

$4xy^3=4y^3x+h'(y)$

Or,

$h'(y)=0$

Integrate w.r.t $y$,

$h(y)=c$.

Putting it all together:

$\Psi(x,y)=\frac{x^3}{3}+y^4x+c$

Comment: Thank you I had just finished working that out as you posted it =)

Comment: Thanks for the question, I'm trying to refresh my calc and diff-eq knowledge.

Comment: I see the error now.  I believe it should be fixed.